# Index unique values in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Not sure how to formulate the question in words, but how can I create an index-column for a data.table that per group increments when a different value appear?

Here is the MWE

```
library(data.table)
in.data <- data.table(fruits=c(rep("banana", 4), rep("pear", 5)),vendor=c("a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "f"))
```

Here is the result the R-code should generate

```
in.data[, wanted.column:=c(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,3)]

#    fruits vendor wanted.column
# 1: banana      a             1
# 2: banana      b             2
# 3: banana      b             2
# 4: banana      c             3
# 5:   pear      d             1
# 6:   pear      d             1
# 7:   pear      e             2
# 8:   pear      f             3
# 9:   pear      f             3
```

So it labels each vendor 1, 2, 3, ... within each fruit. There is probably a very simple solution, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a few ideas. You can use a nested group counter:

```
in.data[, w := setDT(list(v = vendor))[, g := .GRP, by=v]$g, by=fruits]
```

Alternately, make a run ID, which depends on sorted data (thanks @eddi) and seems wasteful:

```
in.data[, w := rleid(vendor), by=fruits]
```

The base-R approach would probably be:

```
in.data[, w := match(vendor, unique(vendor)), by=fruits]

# or in base R ...

in.data$w = with(in.data, ave(vendor, fruits, FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x))))
```

Answer (score 9):

Another approach might be two steps :

```
DT = data.table(fruits=c(rep("banana", 4), rep("pear", 5)),vendor=c("a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "f"))
DT
   fruits vendor
1: banana      a
2: banana      b
3: banana      b
4: banana      c
5:   pear      d
6:   pear      d
7:   pear      e
8:   pear      f
9:   pear      f
DT[, wanted:=.GRP, by="fruits,vendor"]  # step 1
DT
   fruits vendor wanted
1: banana      a      1
2: banana      b      2
3: banana      b      2
4: banana      c      3
5:   pear      d      4
6:   pear      d      4
7:   pear      e      5
8:   pear      f      6
9:   pear      f      6
DT[, wanted:=wanted-wanted[1]+1L, by="fruits"]  # step 2 (adjust)
DT
   fruits vendor wanted
1: banana      a      1
2: banana      b      2
3: banana      b      2
4: banana      c      3
5:   pear      d      1
6:   pear      d      1
7:   pear      e      2
8:   pear      f      3
9:   pear      f      3
>
```

The way I would comment this in production code might be :

```
DT[, wanted:=.GRP, by="fruits,vendor"]          # .GRP is simple group counter
DT[, wanted:=wanted-wanted[1]+1L, by="fruits"]  # reset vendor counter per fruit
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the index to be the *same* for all vendors within a given fruit, then this is another option:

```
in.data[, wanted := as.integer(factor(vendor, levels = unique(vendor))), by = fruits]
```

Otherwise, if you want it to tick up every time the vendor changes, then, from the given answers so far, `rleid` is the only one that works.