# Sequence a column based on two other columns with a restarting sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sequence

I'm working a dataframe similar to the one below where I want to count or have an id based on the name and year, but that restarts when name changes. I've looked at a lot of posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815088/generate-sequence-within-group-in-r), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247414/create-sequential-counter-that-restarts-on-a-condition-within-panel-data-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566562/creating-a-unique-id-in-r)), but most want a non-restarting identifier/counter.

I thought group_by and seq_along would work, but seq_along only takes one variable so this doesn't work

```
df1 <- df %>% 
    group_by(name, year) %>%
    arrange(year) %>%
    mutate(
        exp = seq_along(c(name, year)))
```

I've also tried to use various data.table sequences with .GRP such as the following to no avail

```
df1 <- data.table(df, key="name,year")
df1 <- df1[, Year_id :=.GRP, by=key(df1)]
```

Here's a sample dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = rep(c("A","B"), each=5), 
  year=rep(2000:2001, times=5), 
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Desired output:

```
       name year     Year_id
1        A 2000         1
2        A 2000         1
3        A 2000         1
4        A 2001         2
5        A 2001         2
6        B 2000         1
7        B 2000         1
8        B 2000         1
9        B 2001         2
10       B 2001         2
```

Comment: With `data.table` you could try `dt[,Year_id:=match(year,unique(year)),by=name]` (`dt` is the `data.table` obtained from your `data.frame`).

Comment: @nicola I'd probably use `.GRP` as in Matt Dowle's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35371340/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) dplyr** Create a factor and extract its levels:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   arrange(name, year) %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(Year_id = as.numeric(factor(year))) %>%
   ungroup()
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
    name  year Year_id
   <chr> <int>   <dbl>
1      A  2000       1
2      A  2000       1
3      A  2000       1
4      A  2001       2
5      A  2001       2
6      B  2000       1
7      B  2000       1
8      B  2001       2
9      B  2001       2
10     B  2001       2
```

**1a)** The `mutate` could alternately be written as `mutate(Year_id = match(year, unique(year)))` as per @nicola's comment.

**2) no packages** Without package it could be written:

```
o <- with(df, order(name, year))
transform(df[o, ], Year_id = ave(year, name, FUN = function(x) as.numeric(factor(x))))
```

or using `match`.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(id = cumsum(c(1L, diff(year))))
```

Which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
Groups: name [2]

     name  year Year_id    id
   <fctr> <int>   <int> <int>
1       A  2000       1     1
2       A  2000       1     1
3       A  2000       1     1
4       A  2001       2     2
5       A  2001       2     2
6       B  2000       1     1
7       B  2000       1     1
8       B  2000       1     1
9       B  2001       2     2
10      B  2001       2     2
```