Assign grouping variable/index with repeat ID based on groub_by
I'm trying to mutate this df for two new variables as forms of survey ID. From the df I would like to create a variable "Survey" which would group by "Year" "Date" "City" and then if "Floor" is identical gets the same "Survey". Then I would like a second new variable "Rep" that would simply total the rows from the group by "Year" "Date" "City".
Current df:

Desired df:

I can get "Rep" using the following:
df <- df %>% group_by(Year,City) %>%
mutate(Rep = seq_along(Date))
but am completely stumped on how to generate the "Survey" variable.
This comes close to get my desired "Survey" ID but generates 1,2 for each floor within the group_by
df <- df %>% group_by(Year,City) %>%
mutate(Survey = seq_along(Floor))
Following this answer Assign unique id to consecutive rows within a grouping variable in dplyr
I also get close but each floor within the group still gets 1,2,1,2 rather than 1,1,2,2
df <- df %>% group_by(Year,City) %>%
mutate(Survey =  rep(seq(1,2), length = 2))

Update : This seems to be a way to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796914/sequence-a-column-based-on-two-other-columns-with-a-restarting-sequence?rq=2

This should work:
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Year, Date, City) %>%
  mutate(Survey = match(Floor, unique(Floor))) %>% #Assigns an id number to each of the matches starting from one  
  mutate(Rep = seq_along(Date)) %>%                 
  ungroup()

